# Failed to verify GitHub X-Hub-Signature in my application

Tags: python, git, github

I am using GitHub as my code repositories. I created a webhook for one repository, so when any code change is pushed to this repository, GitHub notifies my app to compile the code. Before compiling the code in my application, I need verify the X-Hub-Signature in GitHub requests, here is what I did in python. I found the signature I computed with the key and payload alway didn't match with the one provided by GitHub. Any idea about this? Thanks!

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import pickle

def compile_code(request):
    payload = pickle.dumps(request.DATA)
    signature = hmac.new(APP_KEY, payload, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
    if signature == request.META.get('X-Hub-Signature'):
        do_compile_code()
    else:
        ...
```

Answer (score 10):

finally the correct way is

```
signature = 'sha1=' + hmac.new(APP_KEY, request.body, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
if signature == request.META.get('HTTP_X_HUB_SIGNATURE'):
    do_something()
```

Comment: Hey, first off thanks for posting the solution you used. I know this is incredibly old, but for those in the future, don't compare using `==` but rather `compare_digest`. I've seen warnings like the following littered in `hmac`'s documentation. 

> Warning When comparing the output of hexdigest() to an externally-supplied digest during a verification routine, it is recommended to use the compare_digest() function instead of the == operator to reduce the vulnerability to timing attacks.

Comment: can someone please tell me how to get request.body in the springboot app.

Answer (score 5):

Example with hmac.compare_digest:

```
def is_valid_signature(self):
    x_hub_sig = hmac.new(
        self.github_hook_secret,
        self.request.body,
        hashlib.sha1
    ).hexdigest()

    return hmac.compare_digest(
        x_hub_sig,
        self.x_hub_signature
    )

def dispatch(self):
    self.github_hook_secret = 'some-secret'
    self.x_hub_signature = self.request.headers.get('X-Hub-Signature').replace('sha1=', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you pickling the data and then calculating the HMAC with it?

Take out the pickling step and use `request.DATA` as supplied in the notification and it should work:

```
signature = hmac.new(APP_KEY, request.DATA, hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
```

(I assume that `request.DATA` contains the body of the HTTP POST, probably it's JSON)

Comment: I tried your way but got an error "TypeError: must be string or buffer, not dict"

Comment: You supplied a `dict` object as either `APP_KEY` or `request.DATA` (most propably the latter). Use the `json` library to convert the `dict` to a `str` object.